# HDD becomes RAW and NTFS again?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

The problem started today after I restart my computer, I started to get a lot of errors from programs that are installed on the E:/ and D:/ partitions (same drive), It starts ok and then suddenly the drive becomes a RAW filesystem (that's what I get from a chkdsk execution). After a long while, the drive becomes again NTFS (Just for some minutes).

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/2r27ho2.png]

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/o6d0dg.png]

[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/2hnchs8.png]

Also, I get a BSOD with the following error: KERNEL DATA_INPAGE_ERROR

My English is poor, so I apologize; What should I do to solve this problem? Maybe the HDD is just damaged?

edit: I also get this from chkdsk

```
Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ...
Read failure with status 0xc0000483 at offset 0x25777000 for 0x8000 bytes.

A disk read error occurredc0000483
Read failure with status 0xc0000483 at offset 0xcc4400 for 0x400 bytes.
The disk does not have enough space to replace bad clusters
detected in file 238 of name .
Read failure with status 0xc0000483 at offset 0x41185000 for 0x10000 bytes.

A disk read error occurredc0000483
Read failure with status 0xc0000483 at offset 0xc69800 for 0x400 bytes.
The disk does not have enough space to replace bad clusters
detected in file 239 of name .
Read failure with status 0xc0000483 at offset 0x40000 for 0x400 bytes.
An unspecified error occurred (6e74667363686b2e b10).
```

Comment: looks like your HDD dies. Post some pictures from this tool: http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html

Comment: Sadly I just bought this laptop a week ago, post edited

Comment: If you bought it brand new from a shop, I'd return the laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I expected the HDD is damaged. The [SMART Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes) shows a large issue with `Reallocated Sectors Count`:

> Count of reallocated sectors. When the hard drive finds a
>   read/write/verification error, it marks that sector as "reallocated"
>   and transfers data to a special reserved area (spare area). This
>   process is also known as remapping, and reallocated sectors are called
>   "remaps". The raw value normally represents a count of the bad sectors
>   that have been found and remapped. Thus, the higher the attribute
>   value, the more sectors the drive has had to reallocate. This allows a
>   drive with bad sectors to continue operation; however, a drive which
>   has had any reallocations at all is significantly more likely to fail
>   in the near future. While primarily used as a metric of the life
>   expectancy of the drive, this number also affects performance. As the
>   count of reallocated sectors increases, the read/write speed tends to
>   become worse because the drive head is forced to seek to the reserved
>   area whenever a remap is accessed. If sequential access speed is
>   critical, the remapped sectors can be manually marked as bad blocks in
>   the file system in order to prevent their use.

Also the high `Current Pending Sector Count` is a bad thing:

> Count of "unstable" sectors (waiting to be remapped, because of
>   unrecoverable read errors). If an unstable sector is subsequently read
>   successfully, the sector is remapped and this value is decreased. Read
>   errors on a sector will not remap the sector immediately (since the
>   correct value cannot be read and so the value to remap is not known,
>   and also it might become readable later); instead, the drive firmware
>   remembers that the sector needs to be remapped, and will remap it the
>   next time it's written. However some drives will not immediately remap
>   such sectors when written; instead the drive will first attempt to
>   write to the problem sector and if the write operation is successful
>   then the sector will be marked good (in this case, the "Reallocation
>   Event Count" (0xC4) will not be increased). This is a serious
>   shortcoming, for if such a drive contains marginal sectors that
>   consistently fail only after some time has passed following a
>   successful write operation, then the drive will never remap these
>   problem sectors.

If this is a **new** laptop, backup as much data as possible and bring it back to the shop, so that they an replace the faulty HDD.