# Can a Windows installation damage an HDD?

Tags: hard-drive

After some research and testing on a laptop that I just bought, I came to the conclusion that the HDD was damaged, [HDD becomes RAW and NTFS again?](https://superuser.com/questions/751872/hdd-becomes-raw-and-ntfs-again)

Now, I send the laptop back to the store, but someone from their technical team said that It was a Software problem, because the person who installed Windows (me) did something wrong, and because I replaced the default Linux system I lost the warranty.

So, my question is, can a Windows installation damage an HDD drive? (The installation worked fine and I just had an issue at the end of the profile configuration).

Sorry for my English (corrections are appreciated), thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loss of your warranty and the damaging of your hard drive are two separate events. They just happened to happen at the same time.

Installing windows did not cause bad sectors to show up on your hard drive, age and or defects in the drive did. If you kept Linux on your system you would have encountered problems there too eventually.

---

To give you a real world analogy: Say you live in an apartment, one day you decide to replace your kitchen floor. While tearing up the floor you find water damage, normally when your apartment has water damage the apartment owner would fix it for no charge. However because you where tearing up the floor when you found it and your apartment agreement does not allow you to replace the floor it is now your responsibility to pay for the water damage repairs.

Tearing up the floor did not cause the water damage, it just caused you to find it. If you had found the water damage some other way the apartment owner would have paid for it.

Comment: The thing is, they gave me a Software warranty, and a Hardware warranty... Of course, I lost my Software warranty when I replaced the OS, but they're saying that I also lost my Hardware warranty because I somehow installed the new OS wrong and that damaged the HDD. So my question is, can that really happen? a damaged HDD because a wrong Os installation?

Comment: You need to read the fine print that came with the hardware warranty. Perhaps it states that if you re-install the OS you loose both warranties. But to say again, the problems you are having from your linked other question can not be caused by a wrong OS installation. Dropping the laptop, sudden power loss during a write to the hard drive, faulty hardware that it got shipped with could all be reasons it could have failed, but just installing the OS will not cause it.

Comment: Well, that answers my question clearly, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely unlikely that by installing Windows in the standard manner you will damage your hard disk. I have installed many OSes onto many hundreds of computers over the last, what, 15yrs and never "damaged" a hard disk.

hard disks are very resilient, but, they do not last forever. This is why we have warranties. The disk is designed to work with whatever you throw at it (within reasonable normal use) and it should last at least the term of the manufacturer warranty.

disks age, other factors like temperature and static discharge can damage disks. Taking these precautions into account your disk can tolerate being formatted many times with whatever OS you please.

Comment: Can the downvote be justified with a reason please?

Answer (score 0):

The technical team's assertion is ridiculous. I've gotten very similar treatment from the store with a big yellow price tag when returning a defective laptop. The hard drive was likely defective from the start, and installing a different OS had nothing to do with the hardware failure.

Depending on where you bought the laptop, the store may just re-image the machine and try to sell it to another customer "preconfigured" for an extra $50-$100.

Although it's outside the scope of SU, my solution would be to return it to the store, tell them the machine is defective, and have them point out which part of their return policy does not permit you to return it for a full refund. If they refuse, call your credit card company on the spot and request a chargeback. Bonus points: wear a suit when you go to return it and be assertive.  Make it clear you have important business to attend to, and that they're wasting your time.